# Is it worth to switch from PHP/MySQL to .NET at this stage?

Tags: php, language-switching

I have 7 years of experience working on PHP/MySQL. From few days I am in a dilemma because not able to see many opportunities in the MNC’s or in banking domain for PHP.

The question comes in the mind is “is it worth to switch from PHP/MySQL to .NET at this stage”

And if I switch without any plan how much money I am going to make. Because at the end everything boils down to money.

Please suggest will this switch help me making good money at this point.

Comment: Is this more suitable for the programmers stack exchange than Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4):

Why switch ? Do both. This will increase your value a lot.

PHP is in some cases a better choice than .NET, while .NET in some cases is a better choice than PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that learning multiple programming languages will enhance our skills, but many companies ask for relative experience in a particular technology like .NET or php. I worked in a company where I developed windows desktop apps using C#.NET but after this, it was very difficult for me to get job even in ASP.NET (in C#).After a long time I got job and on less salary. Currently I am working in ASP.NET but my manager wants me to switch to php. I am also confused , should I work on php or not.I don't want to be "jack of all and master of none". Does relative experience really matters ? plz reply...

Answer (score 1):

**"concepts and logic are important,if you have such a exposure, thats you are more inovative MNC  will hire you . they need to sell you concept not the language skill. they meet clients with the concepts not the technology. so be happy and proud of your skills. and learn more and more to increase your knowledge. programming language play only the way to express concept.""**

i have the same condition some years before. i have a good experience in php, but i face your problem to get into an MNC. so i learn .net. but now i dont have any ambitions like that because.. now i moved to using open source and developed appllcation using php and python... i loved the freedom in developing in open source.. so and so... at last i learned that be expertise in the skills that you earned before..

Answer (score 1):

Treat a language only as a tool, you be the master. The more languages you can work with, your worth will be higher

"The right tool for the right job" - have no idea who said it.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is worth the trouble, as (in my experience) the human resources departments of all companies are fairly clueless, and if someone in the IT department happens to mention .NET, they will discard all CVs without .NET however well-suited you might be.

Or perhaps I'm just getting bitter and twisted in my old age.